# how to select variable in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, variables, select

I should change the my DB into SyBase sql

as I Know double click select the variable

and then I copy the variable and paste

It takes a lot of time

I can't use replace all because there is so many various thing

what is the
Shortcut    to select variable in eclipse

Comment: Shortcut key like ctrl + shift .......

Answer (score 0):

Click on the variable name you wish to rename and press Ctrl+R (Cmd+R for Apple devices), then rename it.